# Evaluating functions at particular points

Tags: equation-solving, functions, simplifying-expressions

I'm a beginner with Mathematica, and I'm running into an issue that I don't quite understand. I define the quantities

```
denom1 = (Sqrt[k^2 + m^2] - p)^2 - k^2 - m^2
```

and

```
denom2 = (-Sqrt[k^2 + m^2] - p)^2 - k^2 - m^2
```

Then, I use the following lines to find their roots, as functions of k, for arbitrary values of p and m:

```
sols1 = Solve[denom1 == 0,k]
sols2 = Solve[denom2 == 0,k]
```

Now, I can store these solutions as variables and everything works well. When I, for example, run the code

```
Limit[denom1,k-> sols1[[1]], Assumptions -> p >= 0 && p \[Element] Reals]
```

the result is zero, which is what I expect. However, if I run a similar code for the other function

```
Limit[denom2,k-> sols2[[1]], Assumptions -> p >= 0 && p \[Element] Reals]
```

the result says

```
2p^2 if p \[Element] Reals && p >= 0
```

which does not make a lot of sense, given that I'm basically evaluating the function at one of its zeroes. Using, for example

```
root1 = k/. sols2[[1]]
Simplify[denom2 /. k-> root1, Assumptions -> p>= 0 && P \[Element] Reals]
```

yields the same result, so now I am at a loss. What kind of mistake am I making, or what am I missing in order to get the right result? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The solutions will not work for all values of parameters. Check this with a predicate for the parameter: `In[429]:= sols2 = Solve[{denom2 == 0, p >= 0}, {k, p}]

During evaluation of In[429]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Out[429]= {{p -> 0}}`. So there are no zeros for `p>0` and at `p==0` the limit is indeed 0.

Comment: Look at: k-> sols1[[1]] , this is: k->k->... There is one "k->" too many. sol[[1]] is good enough